# Mongoose Find() - Return all docs if query is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have mongoose Find code function , the query is recieved from params (Here currently hardcoded)
Suppose this as the query

```
var arrayOfCategories = [ '63073212ed3e0f85ccffc8cf' , '63073324ed3e0f85ccffc8ff']
var arrayOfSkill = []
```

This is my find code

```
const astro =await Astrologer.find({ 'category.astolCat_id' : {$in: arrayOfCategories},
'skills.astolSkill_id': {  $in: arrayOfSkill}})
```

It works fine if I have a value in 'arrayOfSkill' array but I want it to ignore ''skills.astolSkill_id': {  $in: arrayOfSkill}' and only query for arrayOfCategories if arrayOfSkill is blank. If arrayOfSkill is blank then I is returning blank array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build up your query options progressively...

```js
const query = {};
if (arrayOfCategories.length) {
  query["category.astolCat_id"] = { $in: arrayOfCategories };
}
if (arrayOfSkill.length) {
  query["skills.astolSkill_id"] = { $in: arrayOfSkill };
}

const astro =await Astrologer.find(query);
```

Comment: How can i use this with and operation of arrayOfCategories?? that If all the element in the array should match the data in database?

Comment: @unknownGabbar sorry, I don't know what you mean

Comment: Here , For the _ids in arrayOfCategories I want to run 'and' operation in mongo query. Currently it is running as 'or'. It return all the data with even 1 match with 'arrayOfCategories'. I only want that data which matches with all the 'astolCat_id' present in 'arrayOfCategories'

Comment: @unknownGabbar then why are you using `$in`?

Comment: Can you help what else I can use to achieve this. Please